# Are there any online dictionaries that allow you to link to a single specific definition of a word?

Tags: dictionaries

For example, on my blog I want to link to the definition of 'nut' as'a perforated block usually of metal that has an internal screw thread and is used on a bolt or screw' which is the third definition on the page http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nut.

Merriam-Webster only allows linking to the page for 'nut' but not highlight or link directly to a specific definition. In this case the definition I want to indicate is the third. Are there online dictionaries that allows you to link to a specific definition of a word instead of all the various definitions?

Answer (score 2):

Wikitionary has a Contents list for each definition. The links in that table take you directly to the part in question, and you can use that link elsewhere. Try this for example: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blog#Verb